# Отношения таблиц в MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь сделать самый простой тест на PHP+MySQL. Делаю админку. Создаю две таблицы: `questions` и `answers`.

```
@mysql_query('CREATE TABLE questions (
    id_q INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    question TEXT NOT NULL )
    ENGINE=INNODB');

@mysql_query('CREATE TABLE answers (
    id_a INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    answer TEXT NOT NULL,
    id_q INT NOT NULL REFERENCES questions(id_q) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    rw TEXT NOT NULL )
    ENGINE=INNODB');
```

Заполняю таблицы следующим образом:

```
$result0 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO questions (question) VALUES('".$_GET['txt1']."')");
$result1 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO answers (answer, rw) VALUES('".$_GET['txt2']."', '".$_GET['r2']."')");
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO answers (answer, rw) VALUES('".$_GET['txt3']."', '".$_GET['r3']."')");
$result3 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO answers (answer, rw) VALUES('".$_GET['txt4']."', '".$_GET['r4']."')");
```

Хочу, чтобы `id_q` в `answers` принимало значения `id_q` таблицы `questions`. T.е. например:

Вопрос: Сколько планет в Солнечной системе? (`id_q` = 1)
Ответы:

1. 7 (`id_q` = 1)
2. 5 (`id_q` = 1)
3. 9 (`id_q` = 1)

Вопрос: Сколько планет в xxx системе? (`id_q` = 2)
Ответы:

1. 7 (`id_q` = 2)
2. 5 (`id_q` = 2)
3. 9 (`id_q` = 2)

Но у меня получается:

Вопрос: Сколько планет в xxx системе? (`id_q` = 2)
Ответы:

1. 7 (`id_q` = 0)
2. 5 (`id_q` = 0)
3. 9 (`id_q` = 0)

PHP учу 3-ий день, MySQL 1-ый. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересно, а кто будет записывать в таблицу `answers` записи `id_q`? Сами по себе они ниоткуда не возьмутся. Для начала придется откопать `id_q` нововведенной записи. К сожалению, средства PHP и MySQL не позволяют получить его прямо из запроса, поэтому его можно взять из следующего запроса:

```
$tmp_res = mysql_query("select last_insert_id()");
$id_q = mysql_result($tmp_res, 0, 0);
```

После чего вставлять записи в таблицу ответов:

```
$tmp_res = mysql_query("insert into answers(answer, rw, id_q) values('test1', 'rwrw', ".$id_q.")");
```

Comment: спасибо большое. если честно, я уже подумал об этом и пытался таким вот образом получить последний индекс:

    $maxId = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id_q) FROM questions");
    $maxIdFetch[] = mysql_fetch_row($maxId);

ничего не вышло.
а Ваш способо работает.
спасибо!

Comment: Хотя, нет, к сожалению, Ваш способ у меня не получился. Зато помогло вот это:
 $tmp_res = mysql_query("SELECT id_q FROM questions ORDER BY id_q DESC limit 1"); 
 $id_q = mysql_result($tmp_res, 0, 0);

Comment: Странно что last_insert_id у вас не работает.

Comment: Во-первых, если последняя операция не использовала AUTO_INCREMENT, то last_insert_id() возвратит 0!
Во-вторых SELECT id_q FROM questions ORDER BY id_q DESC limit 1 использовать не совсем корректно, так как максимальный ID не обязательно что последний.

Чтобы получить ID последней записи, нужно воспользоваться last_insert_id() (или в PHP mysql_insert_id() ) сразу после INSERT, который использует AUTO_INCREMENT